# Groupby pandas dataframe based on custom list of possible values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to groupby values in two columns. I know all the possible values in the columns. In some data examples certain values in the columns a are not present. I would still like the output of groupby say the len of the group is zero.

```
          s      a  
0  Michaels     FS
1  Michaels     FS
2  Michaels    fds
3  Michaels   fnfe
4  Rogers       FS
5  Rogers      fds
6  Rogers      fds
7  Rogers      ssn
```

I want to groupby both s and a.

```
df.groupby(by=["s", "a"]).size()
```

If you look at the data-sample fnfe and ssn are not present for both Michaels and Rogers. So there will be no output for Michaels-ssn and Rogers-fnfe.

I found a way to get around this by:

df.groupby(by=["s", "a"]).size().unstack().fillna(0).stack()

But then I figured that there is a possibility that there will be several values of a that will be in neither group, but I still them in the output with their value set to zero. The s column does not have such requirements.

Let's say there is another value for the "a" column "adg", that is not present in any example. The desired output would be:

```
s         a   
Michaels  FS      2
          fds     1
          fnfe    1
          ssn     0
          adg     0
Rogers    FS      1
          fds     2
          ssn     1
          fnfe    0
          adg     0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use with  [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and add values to lists with unique values:

```
out = df.groupby(by=["s", "a"]).size()

s = df['s'].unique()
a = df['a'].unique().tolist() + ['adg']

out = out.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([s, a], names=['s','a']), fill_value=0)

print (out)
s         a   
Michaels  FS      2
          fds     1
          fnfe    1
          ssn     0
          adg     0
Rogers    FS      1
          fds     2
          fnfe    0
          ssn     1
          adg     0
dtype: int64
```

Your solution:

```
a = df['a'].unique().tolist() + ['adg']

out = (df.groupby(by=["s", "a"]).size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reindex(a, fill_value=0, axis=1)
         .stack())

print (out)
s         a   
Michaels  FS      2
          fds     1
          fnfe    1
          ssn     0
          adg     0
Rogers    FS      1
          fds     2
          fnfe    0
          ssn     1
          adg     0
dtype: int64
```

Another idea is use `Categorical`:

```
df['a'] = pd.Categorical(df['a'], categories=df['a'].unique().tolist() + ['adg'])

out = df.groupby(by=["s", "a"]).size()
print (out)
s         a   
Michaels  FS      2
          fds     1
          fnfe    1
          ssn     0
          adg     0
Rogers    FS      1
          fds     2
          fnfe    0
          ssn     1
          adg     0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you, really nice solutions. The only difference I used was that I used sets to define the categories, due to not knowing for sure that a value will be missing.